# LFG (Look For Group) command

Tags: discord, discord.py

I was watching a [video](https://youtu.be/GHhArwLCvK0?si=z86SnegJJS7nc30e) in which the YouTuber was programming an LFG (Look For Group) command but in `discord.js`. As I thought that was really cool I tried to recreate it but in `discord.py`. And it looked like this:

```py
group1 = app_commands.Group(name = "look",
                            description = "look - look for group")
group2 = app_commands.Group(name = "for",
                            description = "for - look for group",
                            parent = group1)

@group2.command(name = "group",
                description = "Look for a videogame group!")
@app_commands.describe(game = "The name of the game to search for")
async def lfg(interaction: discord.Interaction, game: str):
    members = [member async for member in interaction.guild.fetch_members()]
    group = []

    for member in members:
        if not member.activities:
            continue

        current_game = member.activities[0].name
        if current_game.lower() == game.lower():
            group.append({"member": member.id, "game": current_game})

    group = group[:2000]

    embed = discord.Embed(color = discord.Color.blurple())
    string = ""

    for value in group:
        member = interaction.guild.get_member(value["member"])
        string += f"Member: **{member.name}** ({value['member']}) is on {value['game']}!\n"

    if string:
        embed.title = f"Members Playing `{game}`"
        embed.description = string
    else:
        embed.description = f" Looks like no one is playing `{game}`"

    await interaction.response.send_message(embeds = [embed], ephemeral = True)

slash.add_command(group2)
```

But it's not working very well... On my discord server, in the command, I put "Roblox" because there was a user who was playing Roblox (f" Looks like no one is playing `{game}`"), when the command was invoked, the message appeared saying that no one is playing the Roblox game while there was a user who was playing Roblox.

I tried to see if it was the intents but it wasn't. I want to get the command to work and the users to appear.